# openGL - Salvar Renderização Complexa na Memória para Restauração Futura

Tags: c++, animação, opengl

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em c++ usando opengl, porém meu conhecimento em c++ e opengl é limitado, principalmente neste último.

Preciso criar um tabuleiro similar ao de xadres, entretanto para cada execução do programa o tamanho do tabuleiro provavelmente será diferente, chegando por exemplo à 1000x1000 casas (nem sempre é quadricular, pode ser retangular também 1000x600). Cada uma dessas casas que renderizo em tela utilizando GL_QUADS é texturização com uma imagem **.PNG** (algumas com canal alpha). **O tabuleiro é diferente para cada execução do programa, mas ESTÁTICO depois de criado**, ou seja, sua aparência não muda no decorrer da execução, mas **sobre ele existem objetos** na ordem de 10% da quantidade de casas que são **dinâmicos**. Assim, se o tabuleiro possui 1000x1000 casas, existem 100 elementos dinâmicos se movendo sobre ele.

Considere que a função "**DesenharTabuleiro(int W, short H){}**" funcione perfeitamente, e seja capaz de renderizar o tabuleiro completamente em tela. Nesta função, para renderizar o tabuleiro eu utilizo o comando for. Eu necessito alterar os elementos dinâmicos pelo menos 24 vezes por segundo, no mínimo, similar à um vídeo. Para isso estou usando **glutTimerFunc** e **glutPostRedisplay**. Ou seja, atualizar a uma taxa de **41 millis** (no minimo).

O problema é que a partir de um tabuleiro 82x82, o programa é **incapaz** de executar 24 atualizações de tela por segundo.

O que preciso é no **início** do programa, renderizar o tabuleiro **uma única vez**, e salvá-lo na memória. Assim, a função desenhar fornecida em **glutDisplayFunc(desenhar);** não criaria toda vez o tabuleiro, mas apenas restauraria seu estado original (inicial), desenhando apenas os elementos dinâmicos sobre ele, reduzindo significativamente a necessidade de processamento, e melhorando a ***PERFORMANCE***. Creio que isso garantiria a capacidade de atualização a cada 41 millis().

## Exemplo:

```c
bool background = false;

void desenhar(){
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);                   // Black and opaque    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);     // Clear the color buffer (background)           

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                             // To operate on Model-View matrix
    glLoadIdentity();  

    // SE AINDA NAO CRIOU O TABULEIRO CRIE
    if (!background){
        DesenharTabuleiro(qtdW(), qtdH());

        // AGORA SALVE A IMAGEM DO TABULEIRO NA MEMÓRIA
        // ISSO QUE NAO SEI COMO FAZER
        SalvarRenderizacaoNaMemoria();

        background = true;
    }else
        // ESTA FUNCÃO DEVERIA PEGAR A IMAGEM JÁ CRIADA 
        // E ARMAZENADA NA MEMÓRIA, E EXIBIR NA TELA
        // SEM A NECESSIDADE DE RECRIAR CADA UM DOS QUADS
        RestarurasBackground();

    /*
     * AGORA REDESENHA TODOS OBJETOS DINAMICOS
     */
}


// DEVERIA SER EXECUTADO A CADA 41 MILLIS, SEM ATRAZO
void Timer(int value) {
    glutPostRedisplay();          //REDESENHA O CENARIO
    glutTimerFunc( 41, Timer, 0); // PROGRAMA A PROXIMA ATUALIZACAO DE TELA
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);                                                                              // Initialize GLUT  
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH );  // Set double buffered mode
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Setup Test");                                              // Create a window with the given title

    glewInit();

    glutInitWindowSize(Tela.width, Tela.height);        // Set the window's initial width & height          
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);                       // Position the window's initial top-left corner
    glutFullScreen();                                   // Exibe em tela cheia      

    glutDisplayFunc(desenhar);                          // Register display callback handler for window re-paint        
    glutTimerFunc( 41, Timer, 0);             // First timer call immediately   

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);             

    glutMainLoop();                 // LOOP PROCESSADOR DE EVENTOS  
}
```

## Solução Possível - FrameBuffer - Não funciona!

Eu tentei realizar o salvamento do tabuleiro na memória através de **FrameBuffer**, mas confesso que não consegui entender seu funcionamento, e nem mesmo como restaurar a imagem depois de salva.

O código abaixo é real, e não surte efeito (a tela fica preta):

```c
GLuint  fBuffer, // FRAME BUFFER
        tBuffer, // TEXTURE BUFFER
        rBuffer; // RENDER BUFFER

GLenum dBuffer[1];  

// ESTA FUNCÃO DEVERIA CRIAR O TABULEIRO E SALVÁ-LO NA MEMÓRIA
// ISSO PARECE NÃO FUNCIONAR        
bool gerarESalvarPlanta(){
    bool retorno = false;

    printf("\r\nRenderizando planta... ");  

    // ##########################################################################
    // CRIA OBJETOS PARA BUFFER
    fBuffer = 0;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fBuffer);     

    rBuffer = 0;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rBuffer);        

    tBuffer = 0;
    glGenTextures(1,      &tBuffer);        

    dBuffer[0] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0;
    glDrawBuffers (1, &fBuffer);        

    // ATIVA O OBJETOS CRIADOS
    glBindFramebuffer(  GL_FRAMEBUFFER,   fBuffer);          
    glBindTexture(      GL_TEXTURE_2D,    tBuffer);    
    glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER,  rBuffer);  


    // ##########################################################################      
    // CRIA A IMAGEM EM BRANCO DO TAMANHO DO MAPA
    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
        0,
        GL_RGB, 
        W(), 
        H(), 
        0,
        GL_RGB, 
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
        NULL
    );

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //GL_NEAREST

    // VINCULA A TEXTURA AO BUFFER  
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, tBuffer);  
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tBuffer, 0);  


    // ##########################################################################      
    // DIMENCIONA O RENDER
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, W(), H());  

    // VINCULA O RENDER AO BUFFER
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rBuffer);  


    // VERIFICA POR ERROS
    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);  

    if (status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
        // PRINTA OK
        printf("[OK]\r\n");  

        retorno = true; 
    }else{  
        std::cout << "[FALHA : " << status ;
        std::cout << " | GlError : " << glGetError() << "]" << std::endl;  
        return false;
    }    


    // AQUI EH ONDE EU RENDERIZO AS CENTENAS DE GL_QUADS
    // DO TABULEIRO, ESSA FUNCAO ESTA FUNCIONANDO PERFEITAMENTE
    // POR ISSO EU NÃO A REPRODUZO AQUI
    DesenharTabuleiro(qtdW(), qtdH());

    // DESATIVA
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);  
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);  

    return retorno;
}

/*
 * DESENHA UM QUADRADO/RETÂNGULO
 * O OBJETIVO DESTA FUNÇÃO E REDESENHAR NA TELA A IMAGEM DO
 * TABULEIRO DESENHADO NO INICIO DO PROGRAMA E ARMAZENADA
 * NO BUFFER
 * >> ISSO NAO FUNCIONA
 */
void buildQuadradoBufferText(float x, float y, float w, float h, float qW = 2, float qH = 2){
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);      

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tBuffer);         
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fBuffer);        

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glTexCoord2f(0, qH);
        glVertex2f( x   , y   );

        glTexCoord2f(qW, qH);    
        glVertex2f( x+w , y   );    

        glTexCoord2f(qW, 0);    
        glVertex2f( x+w , y-h );     

        glTexCoord2f(0  , 0);    
        glVertex2f( x   , y-h );

    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);  
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Peço a gentileza de se possível fornecer um **exemplo prático**.

Agradeço antecipadamente toda ajuda.

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir sem a função DesenharTabuleiro().